# Why whould i call a pointer with no obvious function

Tags: c, pointers, stm32, void-pointers, keil

In an example from Keil uVision for a STM32 Development Board i find the following function:

```
__NO_RETURN static void thrLED(void *argument) {
  ...

  (void)argument;

  ...
}
```

What is the meaning of `(void)argument;`?

As far as i can get it "argument" is a pointer of type void as an argument for the function "thrLED". But i got no clue what the line is doing.

Comment: `argument` has the type "pointer to void", not the type "void". The `(void)argument;` is basically to keep lint (and similar) happy. It basically tells them that yes, I realize an argument was passed to this function. The fact that I'm not using it isn't a sign  of a problem; I meant to do that.

Comment: Without `(void)argument` you will get warning message like "Parameter 'argument' is never used".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Statements of this form are sometimes used to silence warnings about unused objects from compilers or other code-checking tools.

If `argument` is not used in the function, a compiler with elevated warnings enabled might warn that the `argument` parameter is not used.

The expression statement `(void) argument;` nominally uses `argument` in an expression, even though the cast to `void` discards the result. While a compiler could recognize this statement has no effect and warn about that, it is a form chosen to advise the compiler that `argument` is deliberately not used. So compilers are designed not to warn about such statements but to accept them as indications that no warning is needed.